# sqlalchemy is too slow, did i do anything wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

When i do this command using MAMP with mysql:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cont_bar
```

It only takes (264,278 total, Query took 0.0007 seconds.) However, when I try to load this table into a pandas data_frame, it becomes pretty slow. I tried two approaches.

**First Approach**

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, FUTURE_DAILY_BAR_DB))

conn = engine.connect()
resoverall = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM cont_bar")
full_pd = pd.DataFrame(resoverall.fetchall())
full_pd.columns = resoverall.keys()
```

This one takes 20s.

**Second Approach**

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, FUTURE_DAILY_BAR_DB))
conn = engine.connect()
full_pd_2 = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM cont_bar", conn)
```

This one takes 37s. I think this is really slow. Is it the best sqlalchemy/any other mysql based python package can do?

Comment: Comparing a command line tool to pandas that stores data in memory via a special module class (i.e., dataframe) is not equivalent processing. How many fields does this query have? And what data types?